# Retornar registro com maior número de aparições

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, phpmyadmin

Bom, gostaria de saber como retornar o registro com o campo com maior número de aparições em uma tabela do banco de dados do phpMyAdmin.

Veja a imagem a seguir:

[image]

Gostaria de obter "*Joao*". Tentei usar [`mysql_num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-num-rows.php), mas não obtive sucesso.

Há como fazer por `mysql_num_rows`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A query deve ser a seguinte:

```
SELECT nome FROM tbl_abc GROUP BY nome ORDER BY count(nome) Desc LIMIT 1
```

Comment: A query funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode mostrar desta forma usando a seguinte query:

```
SELECT id, nome, count(nome) quantidade FROM tblPessoas 
GROUP BY nome 
ORDER BY count(nome) desc limit 1
```

#### Resultado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Assim como na resposta anterior, funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado!

Comment: Opa! Precisar, só dá um grito aqui @VME Abraços e boa sorte!